# Can I update my Ubuntu 16.04 to 17.10?

Tags: xubuntu

Can I update my Ubuntu 16.04 to 17.10 
Yes/no 
If yes. How can I update my Ubuntu

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: I hope that karel’s and my links each address one of your two questions.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, but you must upgrade to 17.04 first and then to 17.10.  Otherwise, you can wait for 18.04 which will have an upgrade path directly from 16.04.  Given that 18.04 will be released this month, I would wait a bit and upgrade to 18.04.

Comment: No, a direct upgrade from Xenial (16.04) to Zesty (17.04) is unsupported without an intermediate upgrade to Yakkety (16.10). I agree that the best option is likely to upgrade directly to Bionic (18.04) once it is release (not necessarily right away).

Comment: Sorry, yes, I completely agree.  I can't count base Ubuntu releases, clearly :)